# Codeigniter url argument is not reachable by method

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-hmvc

There is a problem that I couldn't solve for hours. As mentioned at title method cannot get the argument from url. I'm using codeigniter + hmvc from below link:

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

This both links addressing same `edit_account` method in accounts controller in accounts module

```
www.site.com/accounts/accounts/edit_account/6

www.site.com/accounts/edit_account/6
```

// method

```
public function edit_account($account_id = false){}
```

But in both ways `$account_id` returns `false`.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you show us your route?

Comment: I forgot that tell you I didn't set routes.php to route this link. But, I put the link of screen shot of my routes.php

SS: http://prnt.sc/b2qa8f

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be using:

```
public function edit_account($account_id = NULL){}
```

using false will always return false regardless of the URI, NULL will set it to NULL only as a default if no arguement is given.

You can then call isset($account_id) or !isset($account_id) as to how to route the query

Comment: Thanks for answer but the problem is not setting default value, the problem is number 6 or other numbers instead of 6 is not reachable. So, I have to find a solution to solve it.

Comment: Did you attempt my answer?

Comment: I already tried this and it didn't change, but I guess I found my mistake. I am going to share here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I missed something that caused this problem. I wondered that can _remap function be caused this issue.

When I checked below link I got it my mistake.

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html?highlight=remap#remapping-method-calls

If I'm wrong correct me please. As I'm concerned, I have to sent parameters from _remap method to requested method.